# Scala App initialization order

Tags: scala

So I have a simple Scala file:

```
object Main extends App {
  println("Init")

  def test=println("Method")
}
Main.test
println(Main)
print("End")
```

and when I run it as a script I get the following output:

```
$ scala Main.scala
Method
Main$$anon$1$Main$@2449a2da
End
```

I am wondering why the `println("Init")` line never gets called? I would expect it to be called on initialization of Main which should happen by the time its method is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at App trait [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.App):

> It should be noted that this trait is implemented using the
>   DelayedInit functionality, which means that fields of the object will
>   not have been initialized before the main method has been executed.

So you have to do something like:

```
object Main extends App {
  println("Init")

  def test=println("Method")
}
Main.main(Array.empty)     // here is the missing call
Main.test
println(Main)
print("End")
```

To get desired output:

```
Init
Method
Main$$anon$1$Main$@37a001ff
End%
```